# How could I fix this error promise error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord.js, unhandled-promise-rejection

If I let several minutes go by without answering I get this error:

> (node:14012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #
> (node:14012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
> This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
> or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:14012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.
> In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How could fix it? I want the time to answer not affect. I try putting "catch" but it doesn't work.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = require("../src/structures/client");
module.exports = {
    name: `quiz`,
    aliases: 'q',
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const preguntas = ['Puedo explicar mis acciones :', 'Las personas no me ven como yo me veo a mi mismo/misma :', 'Pienso en las emociones que conllevan mis acciones : ', "Puedo identificar normalmente mis sentimientos :", "Cada día dedico algo de tiempo a la reflexión", "Puedo mantener la calma, incluso en circunstancias difíciles :", "Soy propenso/propensa a controlar los arrebatos de ira :", "No suelo sentirme desgraciado/desgraciada :", "Me siento calmado y pacífico con las cosas, otras personas o incluso conmigo mismo/misma :", "Suelo controlarme y evitar hacer cosas de las que me arrepiento :", "Generalmente tengo una idea precisa de cómo me perciben las personas con las que interactuo :", "Puedo interactuar con los demás bastante bien :", "Encuentro sencillo entender como se sienten los demás :", "Puedo mostrar empatía y hacer coincidir mis sentimientos con los de otra persona durante una interacción :", "Observo cómo reaccionan los demás para entenderles :", "Admito los errores y me disculpo fácilmente :", "Los demás se sienten bien después de hablar conmigo :", "Puedo reaccionar con calma y sensibilidad ante las emociones de los demás :", "Los demás me respetan y me estiman, incluso cuando no están de acuerdo conmigo :", "Puedo persuadir a los demás para que adopten mi punto de vista. sin coaccionarlos :"];
        const respuestas = `1 ) Nunca
    2 ) Casi nunca
    3 ) A veces
    4 ) Usualmente
    5 ) Siempre`
        const time = 50;
        var autoconciencia = [];
        var autogestion = [];
        var concienciasocial = [];
        var relaciones = [];
        var i = 0;

        function resultados(array1, array2, array3, array4) {
            var resultado_autoconciencia = 0;
            var resultado_autogestion = 0;
            var resultado_concienciasocial = 0;
            var resultado_relaciones = 0;
            var evaluacion;
            for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                resultado_autoconciencia = resultado_autoconciencia + array1[i]
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                resultado_autogestion = resultado_autogestion + array2[i]
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
                resultado_concienciasocial = resultado_concienciasocial + array3[i]
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < array4.length; i++) {
                resultado_relaciones = resultado_relaciones + array4[i]
            }
            if (resultado_autoconciencia < 17 || resultado_autogestion < 17 || resultado_concienciasocial < 17 || resultado_relaciones < 17) {
                evaluacion = "Lo sentimos, no has conseguido el rol-SOPORTE";
            } else {
                evaluacion = "Enhorabuena!!!, has conseguido el rol-SOPORTE";
                // console.log(message.guild.roles);
                // console.log(message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'SOPORTE'));
                let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'SOPORTE');
                if (role) message.member.roles.add(role);
            }
            return {
                resultado_autoconciencia,
                resultado_autogestion,
                resultado_concienciasocial,
                resultado_relaciones,
                evaluacion
            };
        }

        function pusharrays(reaction, array) {
            switch (reaction) {
                case '1️⃣':
                    array.push(1);
                    break;
                case '2️⃣':
                    array.push(2);
                    break;
                case '3️⃣':
                    array.push(3);
                    break;
                case '4️⃣':
                    array.push(4);
                    break;
                case '5️⃣':
                    array.push(5);
                    break;
            }
        }
        nextquestion(i);

        function nextquestion(i) {
            if (i < preguntas.length) {
                message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setAuthor(`${i+1}: ${preguntas[i]}`, message.client.user.avatarURL).setDescription(`${respuestas}`).setColor('#ffdb26')).then(async msg => {
                    await msg.react('1️⃣');
                    await msg.react('2️⃣');
                    await msg.react('3️⃣');
                    await msg.react('4️⃣');
                    await msg.react('5️⃣');
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                        return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
                    };
                    msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
                        max: 1,
                        time: time * 1000,
                        errors: ['time']
                    }).then(collected => {
                        var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
                        var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
                        if (reaction) {
                            if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4) {
                                pusharrays(reaction, autoconciencia);
                                i++;
                                nextquestion(i);
                            } else if (i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 9) {
                                pusharrays(reaction, autogestion);
                                i++;
                                nextquestion(i);
                            } else if (i == 10 || i == 11 || i == 12 || i == 13 || i == 14) {
                                pusharrays(reaction, concienciasocial);
                                i++;
                                nextquestion(i);
                            } else if (i == 15 || i == 16 || i == 17 || i == 18 || i == 19) {
                                pusharrays(reaction, relaciones);
                                i++;
                                nextquestion(i);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
            } else {
                let resultado = resultados(autoconciencia, autogestion, concienciasocial, relaciones);
                message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('#ffdb26').setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/814901488726835261/19e955580ad014d50ec8fde47669696f.webp").setTitle(`${resultado.evaluacion}`).addField("PUNTAJE AUTOCONCIENCIA : ", `${resultado.resultado_autoconciencia}`).addField("PUNTAJE AUTOGESTIÓN : ", `${resultado.resultado_autogestion}`, " ", " ").addField("PUNTAJE CONCIENCIA SOCIAL : ", `${resultado.resultado_concienciasocial}`).addField("PUNTAJE RELACIONES : ", `${resultado.resultado_relaciones}`).setFooter("por: ꧁BOT_DESPACHO_D꧂", 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/814901488726835261/19e955580ad014d50ec8fde47669696f.webp')).then(async msg => {
                    await msg.react('');
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                        return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
                    };
                    msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
                        max: 1,
                        time: time * 1000,
                        errors: ['time']
                    }).then(collected => {
                        var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
                        var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
                        if (reaction == "") {
                            message.channel.bulkDelete(22);
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You receive the error after you *"let several minutes go by without answering"* because you told so.

In your [collector's options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitReactionsOptions) (`{ time: time * 1000, errors: ['time'] }`) you set timeout one of the reasons that cause the promise to reject. If there are no collected messages after `time` seconds, the promise is rejected. As there is no catch block, you'll receive the error you mentioned.

So, add those `catch`es:

```js
msg
  .awaitReactions(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: time * 1000,
    errors: ['time'],
  })
  .then((collected) => {
    var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
    var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
    if (reaction) {
      // ...
    }
  })
  .catch((collected) => {
    console.log(
      `After ${time} seconds ${collected.size} reaction is collected.`,
    );
  });

// ...

msg
  .awaitReactions(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: time * 1000,
    errors: ['time'],
  })
  .then((collected) => {
    var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
    var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
    if (reaction == '') {
      message.channel.bulkDelete(22);
    }
  })
  .catch((collected) => {
    console.log(
      `After ${time} seconds ${collected.size} reaction is collected.`,
    );
  });
```

Comment: now I get the message: After 65 seconds 0 reaction is collected. But It doesn´t fix anything.

Comment: I expect that it doest matter the time and when you react the bot shows the next question.

Comment: Then why did you set a time limit in the options? If you don't want a time limit, you can remove it from the `awaitReactions`' options or increase the `time`.

Comment: I dont know how to delete the time variable without it stopping working :(